# recognize card numbers and expiry date from a credit card using Angular

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, tesseract, capacitor

I'm working on a project. I need to develop a feature that allows users to scan their credit card and automatically extract the card number and expiry date. I'm building this application using Angular.

I was able to convert the image to text using Tesseract.js. But, the data is messy. I can't filter out the card data from the recognized text.

I'm using Angular 15 and capacitor 5.4

Here's the method i've been following.

```
import {CameraPreview, CameraPreviewOptions} from "@ionic-native/camera-review/ngx";
import Tesseract from "tesseract.js";

this.cameraPreview.takePicture({
  width: this.cameraWidth,
  height: this.cameraHeight,
  quality: 100
}).then((imageData) => {
  this.IMAGE_PATH = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.processImage(this.IMAGE_PATH)
  }, 2000);

  this.stopCamera();
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  this.stopCamera();
  this.IMAGE_PATH = '';
  // this.IMAGE_PATH = 'assets/img/test.jpg';
});


async processImage(imageData) {
  Tesseract.recognize(imageData, 'eng')
    .then(result => {
      const extractedText = result.data;
      console.log(extractedText)
      this.processText(extractedText.text)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("OCR Error: " + error)
      this.global.presentAlert({
        head: 'Alert',
        subHead: 'Error Reading Card. pleas try again',
        btn: 'OK'
      }).then(() => {
        this.ngOnInit();
        this.IMAGE_PATH = '';
      })
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to come up with logic to find what you need through that mess. There is no default solution to this.